# Rails routing error when routing to slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a the following link that goes to the correct page i.e. /events/tech/schedule but I get a routing error.

```
<%= link_to "View Schedule", event_sessions_path(@event.slug) %>
```

#### Error

ActionController::RoutingError at /events/tech/schedule
Not Found

#### Routes

```
resources :events do
  resources :sessions, path: "schedule", only: [:index]
end
```

#### Sessions Controller

```
before_filter :find_event

private

def find_event
  @event = Event.find_by(slug: params[:id])
  #@event = Event.find(params[:event_id]) This works if I use <%= link_to event_sessions_path(@event.id) %>
end
```

I don't get any error if I use the event id to link to but this looks ugly and isnt a very good solution.

### Edit - add rake routes

```
event_sessions     GET        /events/:event_id/schedule(.:format)                            sessions#index
```

Comment: Whats the output of `rake routes` ? Does it include `/events/tech/schedule`

Comment: Are you using `friendly_id`?

Comment: No I have a field in the DB for slug.

Comment: `friendly_id` can use this field - it's the best way to manage your slugs (keeps them unique etc)

Comment: Example of using slug if that helps..
match "/:slug" => "pages#show"
And in your controller find the page by slug using this
@page = Page.find_by_slug(params[:slug])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your solution:

```
@event = Event.find_by(slug: params[:event_id])
```

---

When using [resourceful routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) in the structure you have, you'll end up wtih this:

```
events/:event_id/schedule #-> to schedules#index with params[:event_id]
```

The *name* of the variable doesn't matter - it's the content which does. `:event_id` can hold anything (`id` or `slug`), what matters is how you deal with it in the controller

If you change your `Event.find_by` method to use the `event_id` param, you'll be able to find what you need

---

[**friendly_id**](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

A better way to handle this is with [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

If you use the `finders` module in `friendly_id,` you'll be able to search either `id` or `slug` like this:

```
Event.find params[:event_id]
```

Comment: No problem - I'd highly recommend using `friendly_id` :)